# Rename User Attributes - Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a userflow setup for sign-in/sign-up in an Angular AD B2C application.

I know that we can change the text of the User Attributes (which will be rendered in the sign-up/sign-in page), through some settings in the Azure portal because I have already did that once accidentally, to change the display text of the User Attributes.

Now I couldn't find documentations or articles how to rename the User Attributes from the Azure portal.

**For example**: I have a User Attribute called "Given Name". I want to display it as "First Name" in the login page of my AD B2C application.

[image]

How does one to rename the User Attributes for Sign up and sign in userflow?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-user-flow#change-any-string-on-the-page

Comment: The doc is about localization right, by uploading settings through JSON. I'm looking for changing the text of User Attributes through the portal directly. I did it earlier once and I know that there is a provision to do such changes. I just forgot the steps to redo it.

Comment: You want to change the name of the attribute on the login screen - you can do that by localizing it, rather than trying to change its static definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

•   You can do so by enabling the language customizations on the user flow page for the respective user flow created by you for the concerned app. Once, you enable the language customization and select the language of your choice in which you want to customize the user flow, select the page/action for which you want the language to be customized in the ‘Page-level resource files’ section, i.e., Password reset or MFA authentication likewise.

•   Then, click on the ‘Download defaults’ link there above the dialog box where you want to upload the custom policy file for that particular selected action/flow. This downloads the default attributes json file which you can edit in any text editor and upload it as a custom policy or attribute file for the respective user flow or app concerned.

•   In that json file, edit the ‘StringID’ of the default user attributes like ‘DisplayName’ to the one that you want to edit, i.e., ‘Given Name’ and save it and upload that policy in the Identity Experience framework or the respective user flow. This will edit the default built-in user attributes as per your requirement and then you can use them in your app through the custom policy uploaded.

[image: Azure AD B2C Language customization]

[image: Default attribute JSON file]

Please find the below link for more details: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-user-flow#support-requested-languages-for-ui_locales

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer as it solves my requirement. There is an alternate way to achieve this as well which I'm trying to find. It was more user friendly, without having to know about JSON, localization, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to set the Label for any of the User Attributes from the "Page Layouts" settings.

Steps:

- Azure portal -> Azure AD B2C -> Userflows -> (Select the Userflow for which you choose to change the label of the Built-in User Attributes)
- Click Page Layouts -> Click 'Local account sign up page' -> (scroll down to see the options) -> Edit the Label in the last column of the User Attributes table.

[image]

**A bit confusing**
The Label option was not available in one of my other Userflows so that's why I was struggling.

[image]

**Note**: I affirm the Localization settings as the preferred method so I chose that as the answer.